What are the Locust Crusades?
In Exalted 3E, the Crucible of Legend, which is essentially the Storytellers handbook, mentions the Locust Crusades a couple of times in relation to the Alchemicals, particularly in a short blurb on page 152.
I had expected this to be further detailed in the Alchemicals Book. But that is now fully available in draft form and, unless I missed something big, it never mentions it.
The short, blurb in Crucible of Legends makes clear it is about the Octet breaking the Seal from inside and trying to find a way to cure Autochthon in Creation. But it says almost nothing more than that. Basic googling confirms that the Locust Crusades refer to the Alchemicals coming to creation, but most places I found provided even less than the Crucible did.
So, what are the Locust Crusades? The word Crusade generally implies some sort of war. Are the Alchemicals trying to conquer or plunder resources to save Autochthon? If so, what kind of resources are they looking for? And are there plans to discuss them more in 3E, or was that something mentioned almost in passing in Crucible and then abandoned?
I would love a 3E answer, but I'm fairly sure that doesn't exist, so information from prior editions is welcome. The question about "Alternate Locust Crusades" on this site mentions them from 1E, but doesn't say too much about what they are.

What is the Locust Crusade
As you surmised, the Term 'Locust Crusade' refers to, specifically, the Seal being broken and the inhabitants of Authochthon entering Creation and making war, specifically mining it for resources 'like Locust'. We don't know what it will entail in third edition beyond what you already found in Crucible of Legends, but of course we can make some educated guesses based on past edition's portrayal.
History of the Term
The first mention of the concept comes from first edition's 'Time of Tumult', a book containing three adventures, one of which was called 'Crusaders of the Machine God'. The hook at the time was that Autochthonia was running low on Magical Materials and souls, and its inhabitants (specifically one nation) had little choice but to invade Creation to get it. This was the introduction of Autochthonia to the setting, featuring the Crusaders taking over some locations in the South and how things might develop from there and how players could get involved. Thanks to having their own Exalted, as well as a much higher 'tech level' than Creation proper, the invaders are portrayed as winning some easy victories.
'The Autochthonians' was the second book in first edition to mention the crusade (along with giving actual player-facing rules for Alchemicals), featuring a full chapter called 'The Locust War' that elaborated on the adventure in Times of Tumult. A single nation breaks the Seal and invades Creation to gain Magical Materials, souls, slaves and food. Things escalate quite a bit, featuring things like Autochthonians building a huge fleet and defeating the Realm, Deathlords getting involved, the Kukla waking up, etc. (The exact details of the war are somewhat controversial in the fanbase)
In second edition, the only mention I can find of the Locust Crusade is in Manual of Exalted Power: Alchemicals, in the Storyteller section, devoting two pages to the Locust Crusade as well as Grasshopper Diplomacy (Coining the term). Again, the Crusade features Authochthon invading Creation for resources, although they don't go on a Realm-conquering spree as much as in the Autochthonians, while Grasshopper Diplomacy mentions ways of peaceful cooperation and interaction between Creation and Authochthonia.
3e Information on the Locust Crusade

I had expected this to be further detailed in the Alchemicals Book. But that is now fully available in draft form and unless I missed something big, it never mentions it.

This is a stretchgoal in the Alchemicals Crowdfunding campaign. So it will be part of the companion book you'll get if you back the campaign, or something you can buy separately once it's released. See:

At $150,000 in Funding - ALCHEMICALS COMPANION: Locust Crusades and Grasshopper Diplomacy - A Storyteller guide for playing out the first contact between Autochthonia and Creation and the myriad scenarios that might unfold once the Seal of Eight Divinities has been broken.

Given the mention of 'the myriad scenarios', I'd expect this guide to run the gamut from 'full on war of conquest for resources' over tense standoffs to peaceful trade, and how Player Characters from all sides and splats might get involved, adjusted for how some things have been changed in third edition (like no more lack of Magical Materials in Authochthonia).

Great thorough answer!

Excellent answer, and thank you. I backed a while ago (which is how I got the draft), but I missed that entry in the stretch goals. Thanks,

I haven't read the 3e draft yet but I have read most of 2e and some of 1e.
My understanding is that the people of Autochonia are chronically low on resources. Autocthon grabbed all of his followers and what they would need to survive, but his sickness progressed and he fell dormant for thousands of years. His world-body of brass and shadow is not exactly hospitable to life and the Autocthonians have been struggling for survival. Even souls are in short supply, Autocthon grabbed a 100 million of them and set up a system of reincarnation but his followers have managed to grow and expand past his predictions and children are being stillborn as the Well of Souls is stretched to it's limit.
The Locust Crusade/War (known as the 'Fivefold Crusade' to Autocthonians) is a hypothetical scenario where the Seal of Eight Divinities is broken and Autochtnonians go through it to Creation and either grab everything that isn't nailed down to send back to their homes, or start settling in Creation and expanding outwards, turning an ever larger area of it into a paradise for them, which involves a lot more metal and steam than most in creation are comfortable with.
Most of the details for this invasion scenario come from 1e (The Autocthonians - Chapter 5 and Time of Tumult p. 169-175) but 2e seeds the possibility of it as well, hinting at Project Razor and a space-race like struggle to be the first to breach the seal and gain access to the unknowable bounty of creation  (Manual of Exalted Power: Alchemicals p. 227-233, and Compass of Celestial Directions: Autocthonia)
In 1e it is suggested that to form a bridge they stick the head of the Patropolis of Ot through the Seal and it erupts from the ground in a southern jungle where their superior military and technology allow them to conquer such cities as Gem, the Lap, and Paragon. 2e expands on it to suggest this could happen anywhere, such as Cherak, Rubylak or the Wavecrest Archipelago.
